# downloading and saving image in blackberry using php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, blackberry-webworks

I am working on Blackberry webworks App. I am displaying some images on the page. I want to save the image in the blackberry Picture folder if user click on it. I used the following code, but its saving it in the memory card, not in the blackberry picture folder. Following is my code:

```
$file = 'images/' . $_GET['file'];
if (file_exists($file)) {
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($file);
 exit;
 }
```

I have found another way of saving file in blackberry, but I don't understand how to save the image using the following code, its the javascript code that I have got from blackberry forum.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlString = "<test>IO functions</test>";
var filePath = "file:///store/home/user/sample.xml";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
var blob_data = blackberry.utils.documentToBlob(doc);
blackberry.io.file.saveFile(filePath, blob_data);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi asif, actually i am also working on same thing. Not getting it. can you post your code if it is executed successfully.. Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and since I couldn't find any solution in the API, I've decided to develop an Javascript Extension for it. You can download it from GitHub https://github.com/dbotelho/blackberry.io.filetransfer